# C++ Imgui draws over my SDL opengl windows

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

Normally I have blank gray screen which I working on. When I tried to add imgui over it (sdl opengl and sdl directx11) over it. It draws above my real windows, when I made some changes I close that imgui window ,it shows my main window under (that big gray blank screen). Is there a way to add imgui over my gray window?

**First run** : [First start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBdM2.png)

**After I clicked X button top right (my window)** : [Screen which I want to put imgui overlay without having background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyLh5.png)

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 8);
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Moving Objects", 100, 100, 1024, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
    SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
    SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(win, &wmInfo);
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)wmInfo.info.win.window;
    SDL_GLContext ctx = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);



    // Initialize Direct3D
    if (!CreateDeviceD3D(hwnd))
    {
        CleanupDeviceD3D();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    //io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;     // Enable Keyboard Controls
    //io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;      // Enable Gamepad Controls

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
    //ImGui::StyleColorsClassic();

    // Setup Platform/Renderer bindings
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_InitForD3D(win);
    ImGui_ImplDX11_Init(g_pd3dDevice, g_pd3dDeviceContext);

    // Load Fonts
    // - If no fonts are loaded, dear imgui will use the default font. You can also load multiple fonts and use ImGui::PushFont()/PopFont() to select them.
    // - AddFontFromFileTTF() will return the ImFont* so you can store it if you need to select the font among multiple.
    // - If the file cannot be loaded, the function will return NULL. Please handle those errors in your application (e.g. use an assertion, or display an error and quit).
    // - The fonts will be rasterized at a given size (w/ oversampling) and stored into a texture when calling ImFontAtlas::Build()/GetTexDataAsXXXX(), which ImGui_ImplXXXX_NewFrame below will call.
    // - Read 'docs/FONTS.txt' for more instructions and details.
    // - Remember that in C/C++ if you want to include a backslash \ in a string literal you need to write a double backslash \\ !
    //io.Fonts->AddFontDefault();
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf", 16.0f);
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/Cousine-Regular.ttf", 15.0f);
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/DroidSans.ttf", 16.0f);
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/ProggyTiny.ttf", 10.0f);
    //ImFont* font = io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ArialUni.ttf", 18.0f, NULL, io.Fonts->GetGlyphRangesJapanese());
    //IM_ASSERT(font != NULL);

    // Our state
    bool show_demo_window = true;
    bool show_another_window = false;
    ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);

    // Main loop
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        // Poll and handle events (inputs, window resize, etc.)
        // You can read the io.WantCaptureMouse, io.WantCaptureKeyboard flags to tell if dear imgui wants to use your inputs.
        // - When io.WantCaptureMouse is true, do not dispatch mouse input data to your main application.
        // - When io.WantCaptureKeyboard is true, do not dispatch keyboard input data to your main application.
        // Generally you may always pass all inputs to dear imgui, and hide them from your application based on those two flags.
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            ImGui_ImplSDL2_ProcessEvent(&event);
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                done = true;
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE && event.window.windowID == SDL_GetWindowID(win))
                done = true;
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED && event.window.windowID == SDL_GetWindowID(win))
            {
                // Release all outstanding references to the swap chain's buffers before resizing.
                CleanupRenderTarget();
                g_pSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(0, 0, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
                CreateRenderTarget();
            }
        }

        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplDX11_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame(win);
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        // 1. Show the big demo window (Most of the sample code is in ImGui::ShowDemoWindow()! You can browse its code to learn more about Dear ImGui!).
        if (show_demo_window)
            ImGui::ShowDemoWindow(&show_demo_window);

        // 2. Show a simple window that we create ourselves. We use a Begin/End pair to created a named window.
        {
            static float f = 0.0f;
            static int counter = 0;

            ImGui::Begin("Hello, world!");                          // Create a window called "Hello, world!" and append into it.

            ImGui::Text("This is some useful text.");               // Display some text (you can use a format strings too)
            ImGui::Checkbox("Demo Window", &show_demo_window);      // Edit bools storing our window open/close state
            ImGui::Checkbox("Another Window", &show_another_window);

            ImGui::SliderFloat("float", &f, 0.0f, 1.0f);            // Edit 1 float using a slider from 0.0f to 1.0f
            ImGui::ColorEdit3("clear color", (float*)&clear_color); // Edit 3 floats representing a color

            if (ImGui::Button("Button"))                            // Buttons return true when clicked (most widgets return true when edited/activated)
                counter++;
            ImGui::SameLine();
            ImGui::Text("counter = %d", counter);

            ImGui::Text("Application average %.3f ms/frame (%.1f FPS)", 1000.0f / ImGui::GetIO().Framerate, ImGui::GetIO().Framerate);
            ImGui::End();
        }

        // 3. Show another simple window.
        if (show_another_window)
        {
            ImGui::Begin("Another Window", &show_another_window);   // Pass a pointer to our bool variable (the window will have a closing button that will clear the bool when clicked)
            ImGui::Text("Hello from another window!");
            if (ImGui::Button("Close Me"))
                show_another_window = false;
            ImGui::End();
        }

        // Rendering
        ImGui::Render();
        g_pd3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_mainRenderTargetView, NULL);
        g_pd3dDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_mainRenderTargetView, (float*)&clear_color);
        ImGui_ImplDX11_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        g_pSwapChain->Present(1, 0); // Present with vsync
        //g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0); // Present without vsync
    }

    // Cleanup
    ImGui_ImplDX11_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    CleanupDeviceD3D();
 //   SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
 //   SDL_Quit();

  //  return 0;
```

Comment: `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL`, `SDL_GL_CreateContext`, but `CreateDeviceD3D`? Scary. There is no sane way to mix multiple graphics APIs on single window (having it on multiple windows still sounds "unlikely to work" to me but i've never tried that); only use one GAPI. Where is your grey rendering? Sorry I don't see it in preseted code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, without the imgui codes `SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Moving Objects", 100, 100, 1024, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE); `, making me a blank gray window. After I create new imgui frame somehow it draws over my gray window with blueish background. I tried that with usual SDL imgui without CreateDeviceD3D, still same result. I put these screenshots on main thread. @keltar

Comment: Let's begin by clarifying which window you close. Is it top level window created by `SDL_CreateWindow`? Imgui "Hello, world!"? Imgui "Another Window"? You manually modify your `clear_color` and use it as, well, clear colour - that's your background fill. It probably'd be easier to understand if you'd add your initial code without imgui (complete, preferably, or at least main loop).

Comment: @keltar - You the First Start picture on my first post? Program starts like that when I add that codes above. Then If I click the X top right that window closes then starts rendering my actual window "Screen which I want to put imgui overlay without having background" .